# jQuery select2 Form Validation Bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

In my projects I make use of the `select2` plugin extensively but one problem I've had is a bug that affects my form validation logic.

```
var valid = 1;

$('form .required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        valid = 0;
    } else {
        $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }

    console.log($(this))
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

This works for non `select2` form elements but `select`'s initialised with `select2` are incorrectly marked as invalid.

e.g. from the debugging from the above, the `select2` `div` is causing the error because it has no value but the actual dropdown is fine but I didn't expect this to happen  because `div`'s don't have a `value` attribute.

```
div#s2id_select2.select2-container.form-control.required.select2-allowclear
// no value

select#select2.form-control.required.select2-offscreen
// correct value
```

An easy way around this is to have a specific check for `select2` initialised drop-downs but I am hoping to avoid that so that I can use my more generic approach without having to worry about individual cases.

Answer (score 1):

With [Select2 4.0](http://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html), the `.val()` function is supposed to work the way you want it to, but Select2 4.0 is still in beta at this time. Also, it is not backwards compatible with previous versions.

With an older version of Select2, you will have to perform a different check for Select2 elements than for the other elements. You can check `$(this).data('select2')` to see if an element is instrumented with Select2. (It will not be `undefined` if the element is a Select2 element.) If the element is a Select2 element, you can use `$(this).select2('val')` to see if it has a value. That function returns a string for a single select and an array for a multiple select.

```
function isFieldEmpty(field) {
    var $field = $(field);
    if ($field.data('select2')) {
        var val = $field.select2('val');
        return $.isArray(val) ? (val.length == 0) : (val == '');
    }
    return ($field.val() == '');
}

var valid = 1;

$('form .required').each(function() {
    if (isFieldEmpty(this)) {
        $(this).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        valid = 0;
    } else {
        $(this).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that I've just found after posting the question is to update the selector like so:

```
$('.create_form .required').not('.select2-container').each(function() {
```

but maybe there is a more elegant approach.